# How to save contact details from a website to an android or iphone using HTML button with JS or PHP integration?

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a functionality in a website so a user can save the contact details from a website to their phone (android/iPhone) by clicking on an HTML button.

**This is what I tried so far**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="save-btn">Save Contact</button>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Get the contact information from the website
  var contact = {
    name: "John Doe",
    phone: "111551144111",
    email: "john@doe.com"
  };
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  saveBtn.href = url;
  saveBtn.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
});
```

For testing purpose, I uploaded this on a webserver but nothing is happening.

https://cheery-taiyaki-477ee0.netlify.app

Comment: I think it will need to be a 2 step process.  The user will need to first download the vcard and then open it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very close. The trick is to make a new link and set that to your stuff, then click that:

```js
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Get the contact information from the website
  var contact = {
    name: "John Smith",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    email: "john@example.com"
  };
  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
  newLink.textContent = contact.name;
  newLink.href = url;
  
  newLink.click();
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/jOpYYvq

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my first step towards making a large application and I might need more help especially with the data I will retrieve from the database.

Comment: Hass Is there's a way to integrate php coded database variables to this JS function instead of hardcoded name:"John Smith", phone:"555-555-5555", email: "john@example.com"? I have done PHP connection and retrieving data from the database in HTML table but not sure how to implement this function to save database contacts to phone.

Comment: I saw that it was closed, but look into AJAX and JSON. The latter is built into PHP and the former is pretty easy once you get the hang of it. Modern AJAX is [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The “x” in AJAX is usually JSON these days, too.

Comment: I tried this var contact = {
          name: "<?php echo $row["fullname"]; ?>",
          phone: "<?php echo $row["phone"]; ?>",
          email: "<?php echo $row["email"]; ?>",
          company: "<?php echo $row["company"]; ?>",
          socialpro: "<?php echo $row["socialpro"]; ?>"
        };
but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. The trick is to make a new link and set that to your stuff, then click that:

```
               <h1>My Contact</h1>
               <body translate="no">
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Document</title>
                <button id="save-btn">Save Contact</button>
                <script src="script.js"></script>
                <script id="rendered-js">
var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Get the contact information from the website
  var contact = {
    name: "John Smith",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    email: "john@example.com" };

  // create a vcard file
  var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:4.0\nFN:" + contact.name + "\nTEL;TYPE=work,voice:" + contact.phone + "\nEMAIL:" + contact.email + "\nEND:VCARD";
  var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const newLink = document.createElement('a');
  newLink.download = contact.name + ".vcf";
  newLink.textContent = contact.name;
  newLink.href = url;

  newLink.click();
});
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
            </body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).